Mocking AddAsync method in EF Core 8
I want to test following call:
public async Task<ISnapshot> CloneSnapshot(int snapshotIdToClone, string newName)
{
    var snapshotToClone = _databaseContext.Snapshots.Include(s => s.Entries).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == snapshotIdToClone);
    var clonedSnapshot = snapshotToClone.Clone() as Snapshot;
    clonedSnapshot.Name = newName;
    clonedSnapshot.Id = 0;
    clonedSnapshot.IsActive = false;
    clonedSnapshot.ActivationDate = null;

    var newSnapshot = await _databaseContext.Set<Snapshot>().AddAsync(clonedSnapshot);   
    await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return newSnapshot.Entity;
} 

I'm trying to mock database context like this:
   private static ConfigurationProvider CreateConfigurationProvider(List<Snapshot> snapshots)
    {
        var mockDbContext = new Mock<DatabaseContext>(new DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext>());
        mockDbContext.Setup(c => c.Snapshots).Returns(CreateDbSetMock(snapshots.AsQueryable()).Object);
        var snapshotMock = CreateDbSetMock(snapshots.AsQueryable());
        snapshotMock.Setup(_ => _.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Snapshot>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
            .Callback((Snapshot model, CancellationToken token) => { snapshots.Add(model); })
            .Returns((Snapshot model, CancellationToken token) => ValueTask.FromResult((EntityEntry<Snapshot>)null));
        mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.Set<Snapshot>()).Returns(snapshotMock.Object);
        mockDbContext.Setup(_ => _.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(() => Task.FromResult(1));
   
        var provider = new ConfigurationProvider(mockDbContext.Object);
        return provider;
    }

I'm failing to return newSnapshot at following line:
var newSnapshot = await _databaseContext.Set<Snapshot>().AddAsync(clonedSnapshot); 

I suspect that the problem is in return statement (null):
 .Returns((Snapshot model, CancellationToken token) => ValueTask.FromResult((EntityEntry<Snapshot>)null));
            

My callback is getting new cloned snapshot which I'm adding into collection:
.Callback((Snapshot model, CancellationToken token) => { snapshots.Add(model); })

How to modify return in order to make this test work?
.Returns((Snapshot model, CancellationToken token) => ValueTask.FromResult((EntityEntry<Snapshot>)null));

p.s. I did read this question but couldn't make it work
this answer might work but it's really fugly

All i can say is "Yes, mocking a DbContext gets fugly". Hence this is one valid use case for a Repository pattern. (Not a Generic Repository pattern though!)  With a repository we don't care what the repository does, we trust that EF will do what it's supposed to, and is tested. We define a clean boundary that a mock can inspect that "X" method was called and provided this payload and will give back this response in that scenario.

@StevePy you didn't stress "not a generic repository" enough and the OP did just that

There's no reason to call snapshotToClone.Clone() either. The fastest and easiest way is to detach the objects that need cloning, clear their PKs and call context.Add on the root object only. Add will attach all the detached objects in the Added state and SaveChanges will persist all of them.

I had no choice but to modify the code according to this answer and it worked.
private static ConfigurationProvider CreateConfigurationProvider(List<Snapshot> snapshots)
{
    var mockDbContext = new Mock<DatabaseContext>(new DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext>());
    mockDbContext.Setup(c => c.Snapshots).Returns(CreateDbSetMock(snapshots.AsQueryable()).Object);
    var snapshotMock = CreateDbSetMock(snapshots.AsQueryable());
    snapshotMock.Setup(_ => _.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Snapshot>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
        .Callback((Snapshot model, CancellationToken token) => { snapshots.Add(model); })
        .Returns((Snapshot model, CancellationToken token) => ValueTask.FromResult
        (
            new ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<Snapshot>
            (
                new ChangeTrackingInternal.InternalEntityEntry
                (
                    new Mock<ChangeTrackingInternal.IStateManager>().Object,
                    new RuntimeEntityType("Snapshot", typeof(Snapshot), false, null, null, null, ChangeTrackingStrategy.Snapshot, null, false),
                    model
                )
            )
        ));

    mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.Set<Snapshot>()).Returns(snapshotMock.Object);
    mockDbContext.Setup(_ => _.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(() => Task.FromResult(1));

    var provider = new ConfigurationProvider(mockDbContext.Object);
    return provider;
}

@StevePy thanks for the enlightenment, much appreciated 

That's not what StevePy said at all. AddAsync is rarely used because it does NOT add anything, it's a specialized method only used to implement specialized autonumbering strategies that require information from the database. The only thing that saves anything is SaveChanges and that doesn't need mocking either, unless you're in the EF Core team. You aren't testing how EF Core works, you're testing how your code works

You ended up doing the exact opposite of what StevePy said. First of all, you didn't even have to mock DbContext to test attaching objects. You can easily use the in-memory provider. It's unclear if you need AddAsync at all. You don't need to make DbContext or DbSet "generic", they already are. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work for a specific use case, not a connection. You gain little if anything by calling _databaseContext.Set<Snapshot>(), except delaying the initialization of Snapshot metadata.

@PanagiotisKanavos what made you think I didn't understand Steve's comment.
I've started with 'I had no choice but to modify the code ...' and thank Steve for his insight, I wasn't sarcastic.

The point about not creating a generic repository. You don't have to mock DbContext like this either, that's the "ugly" part.  Even a List<T> can be used to mock IQueryable<T> without using any mocking framework.
